cookies on the front or the back?
I am developing an app where in the authentication I decided to do it with cookies, however the question arises: Where to save the cookies? do it from my front end code? or in one of the API routes in the back and then validate the session by making a query to the API to protect the private routes. PD: I am developing with React and Express.

Set Cookies on the Server:
Set cookies from your Express API in the backend rather than directly in the frontend. This approach helps keep sensitive data more secure and avoids potential issues with client-side manipulation. When a user logs in, you can create a session token (like a JWT or a session ID) and set it as an HTTP-only cookie. HTTP-only cookies are not accessible from JavaScript, so they provide an additional layer of security.
